# prevent automatic Update in ClickOnce Application

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I'm develop my update functions with the class ApplicationDeployment to regulate itself. In the project settings -> Publish-> Application Updates I've given my update path and disables all check boxes. Now when I start my application is always installed an update, even if the server is on an older version.
To prevent that automatically shut updates are installed, I should turn off according to Microsoft, the subscription updates in the deployment manifest. I have do it but the automatic updates came everytime when I start my App. How can I prevent this automatic Update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the application only updates if the Version Number changes, so uncheck the box to automatically update the version number on each publish

- Right-Click on Project and go into Properties
- Click the Publish Tab
- Uncheck the "Automatically increment revision with each publish" checkbox

Comment: Thanks for your post. I want to handle my Updates in my own sourcecode with the class ApplicationDeployment. It works fine. The problem is, the automatic Update Window will shown every time but I unchecked the Box 'The application should check for updates'. Unchecked this box should prevent the automatic Update window but it will shown every time.

Answer (score 0):

I sure you click on .application file to run application.