# Prevent check for new version argument for ClickOnce

Tags: c#, clickonce

I am launching a ClickOnce application in the background. The problem is that there is no user interface (in the background with no desktop) to approve downloads the first time. Is there an argument that I could send to *.application file that prevents checking for new versions?

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8149968/prevent-automatic-update-in-clickonce-application)?

Comment: I was hoping there was a command line argument for this when running the application - not when designing the properties of the app.

Answer (score 1):

When you a re setting up your application, in the Application Updates tab, in the very upper left corner, there is a checkbox labeled "The application should check for updates"

Uncheck that and press OK before you make your next build.
[image]

Comment: I was hoping there was a command line argument for this when running the application - not when designing the properties of the app.

Comment: @serializer ClickOnce apps only accept command-line arguments when run from their URL.  And I cannot find a command-line argument to do what you ask.